# New view is not being loaded - am using pushViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, xib, pushviewcontroller

I have spent several hours on this, and tried various things.  I can confirm that the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is indeed being run, and the specific object I am looking for is being returned.

The bit that isn't doing anything is the part where I am trying to display the SensDetailViewClass view.   It runs the code, but the viewDidLoad method in SensDetailViewClass.m doesn't run, and the view doesn't change.

I would like to have the SensDetailViewClass displayed.   I can confirm that the .xib file's owner is the SensDetailsViewClass.

Please help.  Here's the code.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// get the selected item
Sens *info = [_sensInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// initialise the detail view controller and display it
SensDetailViewClass *details = [[SensDetailViewClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];

// set the title of the page
[details setTitle:info.heading];

details.selectedSens = info;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
[details release];

}
```

UPDATE:  I got it to work by using this mechanism: 
    [self presentModalViewController:details animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SensDetailViewClass *details = [[SensDetailViewClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"SensDetailViewClass" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
```

i think you are fresher so nedd to check the link of tutorial

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand what I must do.  Please explain.

Comment: tell me nibname of SensDetailViewClass.

Comment: The SensDetailViewClass is being initialised, however the viewDidLoad is not running.  In fact, it gets initialised if I initWithNibName "MainWindow" or "SensDetailViewClass".

Comment: Check given url in answer. it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, I have checked it out and gone through it carefully, however I am still having difficulty getting my solution to work correctly.   I have created a new item - Test.m which created Test.h and Test.xib - which I have also tried to display, but that's not working either.   My solution was originally created as a tab-bar application - not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: I eventually found something that worked - instead of the above I used this:
    [self presentModalViewController:filtersViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your `SensDetailViewClass`  class has `MainWindow` as its .xib file?

Please check it and replace nib name `

```
initWithNibName:@"MainWindow"
```

in above code

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Where do I check this?  I am using XCode 4.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Are you sure y**ou have the navigation comptroller in the app** or its just the View Based application.

IF this is ok then ,
2)

```
// initialise the detail view controller and display it
SensDetailViewClass *details = [[SensDetailViewClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"You-Xib name for this View" bundle:nil];

// set the title of the page
[details setTitle:info.heading];

details.selectedSens = info;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
[details release];
```

Comment: Thanks - I got it to work with this mechanism: [self presentModalViewController:filtersViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Yes...But that won't let you to move on other pages ...if you are looking for something like navigation ... whereas presentModal opens a new view from scratch.

Comment: I have a list of news items in a UITableView.  When one is selected then I want to display the news content.   presentModal appears to be able to give me what I want, as long as I can close the view and return to the list of article id's.